# Memory Leak in xcode project (iphone app)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I have a memory leak issue which is driving me crazy for 2 days.

```
Leaked object: GeneralBlock-96, CALayerArray, _ NSArrayM, UIGestureRecognizerTarget, UITableViewCell, _NSCFSet, UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Responsible library: QuartzCore and UIKit
```

The responsible library doesn't show any code from my project. It just shows `UIKit` and `QuartzCore`. Even when I tried to trace it down it doesn't show anything from my code. Also I'm able to replicate this only when I test it from my device (not always). Am I doing anything wrong? and do I have to worry about this leak?

Comment: Does this leak only occur once per run? It's not unknown that some Apple APIs produce small leaks. If it doesn't show any of your code, I wouldn't worry about it too much.